# Wait for an event to trigger inside Node.js process

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, authentication, xmpp

First of all, I am well aware that Node.js is non-blocking before anything else, but in this very specific case, it must be blocking and waiting here.

I have an authentication process that works that way (using APIs, I didn't design this so I cannot modify the way the auth works):

I send a PUT request to a REST API, I get a HTTPResponse code that determines if the API understood the request.

The server I just requested through its API sends the full response (including error codes, etc) through an XMPP protocol.

This means, when I send the request, I cannot know what happened next, and must wait for the XMPP event to trigger (basically, an on("message", callback) event).

I'd like to know how to work with this with Node.js.

Two more things to know:

1) I'm working on a client/server architecture, and my Node.js server is doing this authentication process, and sending a response through the websocket to the client and waiting for a socket answer is out of the question (not my call, but my boss wants this process to be done in one pass).

2) It must not be done with the client socket and must go through the full Node.js process for various reasons.

Thanks a lot for your help people! \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not answering previously, we had some severe hardware failure at work.
Anyway, I'm not answering one of your comments directly because I found a solution I prefer, even if I thank you for your help. I've decided to use a promise and to wait for its answer to be sure to get a proper response.

Here is the code:

```
var answer = await new Promise((accept, reject) => {

    // If there are no stanza in 30 seconds, then the process failed or the stanza got missed.

    setTimeout(() => {

        reject("timed out");

    }, (30 * 1000));

    // Waiting for the xmpp event to trigger.

    xmpp.on("stanza", function(stanza) {

        // Processing of the received stanza goes here.

    });

});
```

@gkatzioura solution was interesting, but this looked a little bit heavy on bandwidth and we are working on a large scale applications, or maybe I didn't fully understand it, then it is my mistake.

@pspi solution was also interesting but this would be a problem considering the XMPP event listener is inside the request, and the PUT request needs to send a body on its end() event and here it wouldn't really work for what I want to do. I think that's because the original post I made was somewhat unclear.

Thanks a lot for your help guys! :]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough XMPP, but would this just be case of "putting dependent logic inside callback".

```
request.put(..., function () {
    // dependent xmpp logic inside request callback
    xmpp.on(..., function () {
        // xmpp and put response received, now talk back to socket client
        socket.send(...);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would proceed with the event [emitter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_emitter.htm) (or anything in a publish subscribe fashion).

Fire your http call and inside the handler add an emitter listener with a check if the events is for the corresponding authentication.
Meanwhile your xmpp connection once it receives the authorization it shall emit a message.
The listener will receive the message successfully and will use the callback of the http call.